# Programmatically adding Component into other Component lost all properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using ember-cli (Ember: 1.10.0) and want to create a modal container which will act like a stack of modals. Each modal is a component and they could interact to the previous/next one.

My code is like

modal-container

```
var ModalContainer = Ember.Component.extend({
  handler: {},
  handlerFunction: function () {
    var handler = this.get('handler');
    if (handler.action === 'push') {
      var instance = handler.component.create({
        content: handler.content
      });
      this.get('modal-container').pushObject(instance);
    } else {
      this.get('modal-container').popObject();
    }
  }.observes('handler'),
});

// template
{{view Ember.ContainerView viewName="modal-container"}}
```

And a dummy modal like this

```
var DummyModal = Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['dummy-view-0'],
    content: 'dummy-view-0'
});

// template
<div>{{content}}</div>
```

If I use `{{dummy-modal}}` in template, I could see a `div` with `dummy-view-0` content in it. But if I programmatically insert it via `ModalContainer.handlerFunction`, I could get the `div` element but neither my `handler.content` nor default `dummy-view-0` will present in `{{content}}`.

What do I miss?

Also, I get using global lookup for `Ember.ContainerView` is deprecated. What is the corresponding string for this? On official website it only mention `'select'`...

=== edited on March 6 ===

I found that the `DummyModal` component created by `.create()` in `ModalContainer` does not automatically use the template in `/templates/components/` and it fetch `content` from `ModalContainer`, so basically it behaves like a View. Does anyone know how to let it use the default template like inserting it via helper in template, and how to specify the corresponding context and controller? I found the concept of the following code in latest `Ember.Component.init` source code

```
var instance = handler.component.create({
   ...
});
instance.set('context', instance);
instance.set('controller', instance);
```

but it doesn't work